# Split to array and fill combobox with unique

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a dynamic

```
range("A1:ZZ1")
```

In this range each cell comma separated values

```
cell("A1")= "City, street, Nr" and etc...
```

I have two comboboxes
`In first, i must select from all cities in range, show only Cities name`

```
for each cell in range("A1:ZZ1")
  CitiesArr(x) = split(cell.value,",")
  x=x+1
next cell
me.combobox1.list CitiesArr(1,1) ???
```

`In second, i must depending on first selected city, select from all selected cities in range`

```
If me.combobox1.value="Moscow" then me.combobox2.list = CitiesArr(which contains "Moscow")
```

I confusing how to do that ((

```
So if 
cell("A1") ="Moscow, Lenin str.,12"
cell("B1") ="Moscow, Centralnaja str.,1"
cell("C1") ="Moscow, Lenin str.,98"
cell("D1") ="Krim, Chingis str.,23"
cell("F1") ="Krim, MUrashev str.,45"
....
cell("ZZ1") ="Belostok, Kazik str.,6"

in combobox1 I must have UNIQUE (sort Desc)

Moscow
Krim
....
Belostok

If I select in combobox1 field Moscow then in combobox2 i must see (sort Desc by Street column)

Moscow, Lenin str.,12
Moscow, Centralnaja str.,1
Moscow, Lenin str.,98
....
```

Comment: I dont understand what you are doing here.. Can you show a screenshot of your spreadsheet? are you sure you want to iterate just the first column? `range("A:ZZ1")` should rather be `range("A1:ZZ1")` possibly because the first one is an invalid range anyway as there is a number missing after A. How did you dimension `CitiesArr`?

Comment: well, why don't you create a Collection of all Cities first and use that as a Source for the combobox? Then based on change events of combobox populate the other ones. If I were you I would build an in-memory model for it first so I could access all the data I need relatively easy

Comment: I Cant create collection of cities because I dont know which cities will be added in future, and database every day is updated with new cities

Comment: Siddharth Rout It is easy for you not form me? please show an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

I have taken sample data in just 5 cells for demonstration. Please change code as applicable.

```
Option Explicit

Dim aCell As Range

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    '~~> Change Sheet1 to the relevant sheet name
    '~~> Change A1:E1 to the relevant range
    For Each aCell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E1")
        If InStr(1, aCell.Value, ",") Then _
        ComboBox1.AddItem Split(aCell.Value, ",")(0)
    Next aCell

    '~~> Remove duplicates
    RemoveDuplicates ComboBox1
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Dim tmpStr As String

    ComboBox2.Clear

    For Each aCell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E1")
        If InStr(1, aCell.Value, ",") Then _
        tmpStr = Split(aCell.Value, ",")(0)

        If Trim(ComboBox1.Value) = Trim(tmpStr) Then _
        ComboBox2.AddItem aCell.Value
    Next aCell
End Sub

'~~> Procedure to remove duplicates
Private Sub RemoveDuplicates(cmb As ComboBox)
    Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer

    a = cmb.ListCount - 1
    Do While a >= 0
        For b = a - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If cmb.List(b) = cmb.List(a) Then
                cmb.RemoveItem b
                a = a - 1
            End If
        Next b
        a = a - 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: First combobox must have unique values, no duplicates and sorted Desc and second combo must sorted Desc by streets names!!! It is very important

Comment: Thats easy again. One moment.

Comment: Updated. You may have to refresh the page.

Comment: ok Thank You very Much. it is good enought!! but now imagine what Range contains 100.000 columns? Your code will works fast? And what about sorting descending?

Comment: Excel has only 16384 columns. Is it fast enough for that number? Good question! one which can easily be verified by yourself ;) My code took less than 1 second on 15201 columns.... BTW

Comment: `And what about sorting descending? –  user3588043 5 mins ago` Well I think I have given you enough ammo to figure that out yourself? ;)